# Return custom error messages in Spring Security class that implements UserDetailService

Tags: spring, spring-security, authorization

In my authorization server, I have a class in that implements UserDetailService and overrides loadUserByUsername. I load user from my database and hand it over to spring securtiy. Everything works fine bc spring security checks the passsword and all that stuff before returning the jwt token.

Now I have to do some more checks on the user before I want spring to do authorization. For example we want to check isAccountLocked or isEmailVerified etc. If any of this is true then I want to throw an exception which states watever the issue is so that the fron-end can display the appropriate message to the user. This is bussiness rquirement.

I tried to extend "UsernameNotFoundException" and throw that but the problem is regardless of what exception I throw Spring Security still just returns a 400.

```
{
    "error": "invalid_grant",
    "error_description": "Bad credentials"
}
```

I also tried adding custom authenticationEntryPoint in my config class the extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter but it does even reach any breakpoints set in that class. I still get  the 400 in postman.

```
@Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.cors().disable()
            .csrf().disable()
            .exceptionHandling().authenticationEntryPoint(authenticationEntryPoint());
    }
```

Simply put when UsernameNotFoundException is thrown I want to be able to put a custom error messages as to why it is thrown or I want to throw some custom exception that extends UsernameNotFoundException.

Any help will be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Hi Guys just an update i managed to solve my problem with the followig.

First disable hiding of username not found exception in class that extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter.

```
 @Override
    @Autowired
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) {
        DaoAuthenticationProvider daoAuthenticationProvider = new DaoAuthenticationProvider();
        daoAuthenticationProvider.setHideUserNotFoundExceptions(false);
        daoAuthenticationProvider.setPasswordEncoder(passwordEncoder);
        daoAuthenticationProvider.setUserDetailsService(ctnwUserDetailsService);
        auth.authenticationProvider(daoAuthenticationProvider);
    }
```

Then configure exception translator to catch UsernameNotFound exception and return
ResponseEntity with custom exception as body. This is in class that extends AuthorizationServerConfigurerAdapter.

```
@Override
    public void configure(AuthorizationServerEndpointsConfigurer endPoints) throws Exception {
        TokenEnhancerChain tokenEnhancerChain = new TokenEnhancerChain();
        tokenEnhancerChain.setTokenEnhancers(Arrays.asList(new 
   CustomTokenEnhancer(userBean), accessTokenConverter()));
        endPoints.tokenStore(tokenStore())
            .accessTokenConverter(accessTokenConverter())
            .authenticationManager(authenticationManager)
            .userDetailsService(ctnwUserDetailsService)
            .tokenEnhancer(tokenEnhancerChain)
            .exceptionTranslator(exception -> {
                if (exception instanceof UsernameNotFoundException) {
                    return ResponseEntity
                        .status(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST)
                        .body(new CustomOauthException(exception.getMessage()));
                } else {
                    throw exception;
                }
            });
    }
```

Finally so can throw UsernameNotFoundException in class that implements UserDetailService.

```
public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String username) throws 
UsernameNotFoundException {
        WebUser webUser = webUserRepository.findOneByUsername(username);                
        if(!webUser.getIsEmailVerified()) throw new  UsernameNotFoundException("User email not verified");
}
```

The result will be like below

[image]